# Better way to keep track of questions

Tags: discussion, feature-request, questions, organization

As I've started to ask more questions on StackOverflow, I've realized it would be nice to be able to separate my questions into at least 2 groups, if not 3 groups.

- Unanswered
- Answered
- Accepted Answer

I find I'm generally adding info from suggestions/comments to my unanswered or answered questions that I haven't yet accept an answer on. It also helps to be able to keep track, these are the 3 or 4 questions I still need answers on, and I might need to possibly add a bounty, improve the question, check my existing comments/answers, etc.

I'm guessing this data is tracked at the database level already?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Low tech solution: use the search feature and your browser's bookmarks.

- [user:me is:question hasaccepted:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aquestion+hasaccepted%3A0&submit=search)
  Questions you have not accepted an answer to
- [user:me is:question answers:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A0)
  Questions that have not yet received an answer at all
- [user:me is:question answers:1 hasaccepted:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3Ame+is%3Aquestion+answers%3A1+hasaccepted%3A0)
  Questions that you have not accepted, but do have at least one answer

Comment: Hah, very cool, didn't know I could do that, or better phrased, didn't think of doing that!!!